# How do I get list of paths that exclude certain subdirectories

Tags: linux, grep, ls

I want to copy all my projects to google drive using rclone, but I don't want to copy files in directories like node_modules,
Example:
root: project
subdirecotry: myBlog/node_modules/, myBlog/backend/node_modules.
I am an beginner in Linux so I don't know how to achieve it using find, grep, etc.

Comment: See https://rclone.org/filtering/

Comment: You can use `rsync -av --exclude=PATTERN SRC DEST`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two questions.

1. How to list paths that exclude certain subdirectories
2. How to exclude certain subdirectories when using `rclone`

## Listing

Use the `find` command. Here is an example directory with three subdirectories:

```
ls

one two three
```

To output a listing of only `one` and `two`, omitting `three`, use `find` like this:

```
find . -type d -not -path ./two
.
./one
./three
```

## rclone

Use the `--exclude` switch, to exclude the contents of specific subdirectories - in this example, the subdirectory `two` (underneath `stackoverflow`), would be ommitted in the sync to `destination`:

```
rclone sync stackoverflow/ destination/ --exclude='two/**'
```

See the `rclone` [documentation](https://rclone.org/filtering/) for further details.